# Converting image to base64

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, windows-phone-8, base64

I have the following code to convert image to base64:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("Checked.png", UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

    }
```

And the following code to get Bitmap image form base 64:

```
public static BitmapImage base64image(string base64string)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

So when i convert and deconvert it is blank.

I know that deconverter works, because, when i give him exact string:

```
string base64="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";
```

Which is my Checked.png converted in online converter. It decompreses perfectly.

And this is my base64, which i get by converting:

```
"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"
```

**My problem is that string which i get as base64 from my code - is incorrect** **What i did wrong?**

Comment: Please add question/problem to your statements. So far there is nothing glaringly bad in the sample  nor any information on what does not work/what errors do you get.

Comment: where are u getting problem or whats not working ?

Comment: What do you mean "incorrect"? Your byte sequence represent perfectly valid **jpg** image of a check mark...

Comment: Incorrect is that when i decrypt it - it is just a black rectangle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about trying:

```
public static BitmapImage base64image(string base64string)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
    {
        Image streamImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        streamImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return streamImage;
    }
}
```

I agree with Alexei that your code for reading the image in does look a little strange. I've recently written some code for a similar task that I was doing which might point you in the right direction:

```
       string fileContent = null;
        /* Check the file actually has some content to display to the user */
        if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[uploadFile.ContentLength];
            int byteCount = uploadFile.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)uploadFile.ContentLength);
            if (byteCount > 0)
            {
                fileContent = CreateBase64Image(fileBytes);
            }
        }

    private string CreateBase64Image(byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        Image streamImage;
        /* Ensure we've streamed the document out correctly before we commit to the conversion */
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
        {
            /* Create a new image, saved as a scaled version of the original */
            streamImage = ScaleImage(Image.FromStream(ms));
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            /* Convert this image back to a base64 string */
            streamImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about if i dont use the streamImage.save with the extension format... wouldn't be straigth forward Convert.ToBase64String without explicitly mentioning the extension?

Answer (score 2):

not an answer: more of a long comment  ... OP states that decoding code works perfectly fine, also it looks suspicios. Also code assumed to be verified to work on PNG images, but saving code explicitly produces valid JPG with `SaveJpeg` call...

---

Your code that creates stream for reading looks strange - you create stream over existing byte array, than write the same bytes into that stream, and that pass that stream without seeking back to 0 to some method.

Potential fix (assuming `BitampImage` can accept JPG stream):

- don't call `Write` at all as stream already have the bytes you want
- set `ms.Position = 0` after writing to the stream.

Note: I'm not sure if it is OK to dispose stream that is a source for `BitmapImage`, you may need to remove `using` too.