# MVC4 : export qrcode image to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to export excel sheet with qr-code images in my table.  The qrcode saved with its serial number and i generate it with google apis.  I do it in controller that return `MvcHtmlString` and i use it in my view like `@Html.QRCode(item.SerialNumber, 80, 0)`
and it works in my view well.

my Controller

```
  public static MvcHtmlString QRCode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string data, int size = 80, int margin = 4, QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel errorCorrectionLevel = QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel.Low, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    if (size < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size", size, "Must be greater than zero.");
    if (margin < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("margin", margin, "Must be greater than or equal to zero.");
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel), errorCorrectionLevel))
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("errorCorrectionLevel", (int)errorCorrectionLevel, typeof(QRCodeErrorCorrectionLevel));

    var url = string.Format("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chld={2}|{3}&chs={0}x{0}&chl={1}", size, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data), errorCorrectionLevel.ToString()[0], margin);

    var tag = new TagBuilder("img");
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
        tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    tag.Attributes.Add("src", url);
    tag.Attributes.Add("width", size.ToString());
    tag.Attributes.Add("height", size.ToString());

    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

To export excel sheet i do the following :

1. create a grid
2. give it the Data Source of the desired data .

the qrcode data that i give to the grid view is

`data.QRcode = atm.SerialNumber;`

it actually get the string of qrcode how to get its qrcode image of its code like in my view that i use

`@Html.QRCode(item.SerialNumber, 80, 0)`

Note : i need any solution that can get the qrcode image and other data external to print it.

Update : I reached to the source of the image then if any solution for how to display image in excel sheet according to the source of the image .
detailed steps : 
1- get the link of the image like with google apis

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

            image.ImageUrl = url;
            image.Width = 80;
            image.Height = 80;
            atm2.QRcode = image;
```

but this column doesn't appear in the exported excel sheet

Thanks for any help .

Comment: have you tried base64 encoding the image? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64

Comment: No , because i cannot convert string to qr code i use it in a controller to use it as a tag in the view and i don't know how to use it in a controller

Comment: it isn't entirely clear from your post. What is your actual question?

Comment: I can get the string url with google apis like
[link](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chld=Low|4&chs=80x80&chl=25981017)
but i try to hold it as an image and display it in the excel sheet
then i try to change data type of qrcode to Image and  wirte
 `image.ImageUrl = url;
               // image.ResolveUrl(url);
                image.Width = 80;
                image.Height = 80;

                atm2.QRcode = image;`
but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what your "atm2.QRCode" business is, but it should work if you do Image image = new Image(); image.ImageUrl = <your url>; my guess would be that your other code/control is messed up. You can export image tags to excel just fine http://forums.asp.net/t/1056951.aspx?How+to+export+an+image+to+excel+Using+ASP+NET+2+0+and+VB+

Comment: atm2 is object and qrcode in an image type and i put all data in this object to use it in grid view but the qr image doesn't appear . 
i use your recommendation and put the values in html tags and export word file then the images appear well . but the other text data doesn't appear in its uni code and when i put the ` "<html encoding='UTF-8'> "` the the exported word file was unable to open

Comment: my tag :
`string tags = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>";
 tags += " <html><table><th>  Bank Name  </th><th>  Governate  </th><th>  Area  </th> <th>  Address  </th><th>  ATM Number  </th>  <th>  Serial Number  </th>  <th> QRcode</th></tr>";
then why when "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" is exist the file doesn't work if any solution to run its in uni-code or 
if i can return back to the method of grid view and put the column that hold image with html tag ?