# Replace image link in HTML with base64 file embedded (HTML script is in SQL Server)

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

I have got some HTML stored in a SQL database which contains links to images (img src tags)

I need to find a way of replacing the links with the actual file embedded in base64 format and copying it to a different table.  I can't think how best to achieve this?

The reason for it is that I need to migrate some HTML knowledge documents from one system to another and the other system requires the images to be embeded.

I am using MS SQL Server and Visual Studio (c#)
Thanks

Comment: Each individual step answered many times on SO already. You should simply hire someone to stitch them together... or maybe narrow down question to particular problem you faced doing so.

Comment: Try search before you post. You may want to write a job that downloads all the images and convert them into base64 format and save it into DB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64