# How to Serialize the fingerprint of Green Bit DactyScan84c in C# and save it into database

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I wanted to Serialize the fingerprint of Green Bit DactyScan84c in C# and save it into database. Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sdk is included with the device. Surely this is just a case of getting the image(s) and saving it/them to a database?

Comment: @Kell thanks for the reply. Ya you are right. I wanted the image to be stored in XML format. can you please help with this.

Comment: Images are binary. xml is a string. You'd have to encode the image to a string and stick it into xml. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/converting-image-to-base64